# MFC: change font size on static control doesn't work?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I try to use this code [MFC: Dynamically change control font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617199/mfc-dynamically-change-control-font-size), but doesn't seem to work.

```
CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    ...
    LOGFONT lf;
    CFont *currentFont = GetFont();
    currentFont->GetLogFont(&lf);
    lf.lfHeight = 60;
    CFont font;
    font.DeleteObject();
    font.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC)->SetFont(&font, TRUE);
    ...
}
```

It doesn't matter which "lfHeight" I set, the font size remains unchanged.

Comment: `CFont font;` is a local object, no wonder it doesn't work. Move it to the class members scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jovibor said that, the `font` is a local object, after the function is called, the object will be released. When drawing a static control, the text will still be drawn with the default font.

Simple way:

- add `static`

  like this: `static CFont font;`
- Declare an object in a class

  ```
  class CMyDialog : public CDialogEx
  {
  ....
  private:
      CFont font;
  };
  ```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. But I would say defining a "Set..." function like this is weird.